# Каким инструментам в JavaEE отдать предпочтение?

Tags: java-ee

Я только начинаю знакомиться с JavaEE, более-менее умею работать с jsp, servlet, filter. 
Пытаюсь сделать свою научную работу "по уму", чтобы все как у людей)

Но читая статьи в интернете часто сталкиваюсь с примерами веб-приложений где используются всякие EJB, JSF, Spring, JAAS и еще куча-куча умных слов. Пытался изучить EJB, но там жесть какая-то. Возможно эти технологии уже не используются, или им есть замены.

Подскажите какие инструменты (технологии) стоит все-таки изучить, и применять в работе?
Если не сложно то укажите причины и цели использования данных инструментов (технологий).

Comment: >Пытался изучить EJB

А вы попробуйте поучиться программировать. Тогда и технологии проще выбрать будет :)

Comment: "попробуйте поучиться программировать" - сказано с иронией) Я рад что Вы все это знаете

Comment: Это не ирония, это вполне серьёзно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы советовал Spring, но для него нужен jstl:) 
EJB возможно стоит, но не в первую очередь, Spring сейчас более востребован.

Spring - гибкий)

Comment: Аргументируйте минус, пожалуйста. Интересно, где я не прав.

Comment: я не знаю за что вам минус поставили) но на каждый - есть свой +